# Number of classes in SOM

Tags: neural-network, classification

I have some test results in an NxN matrix which counts total fail results for that cell. I want to see if the failures generate any geometric patterns that can be identified automatically.

The approach I am planning is, I want to use the result matrix and use a Neural Network to Generate Classification. From the classification I want to see if it was actually able to find out some classes that the failure patterns can be identified spatially.

So I was planning to use [kohonen SOM](http://www.pymvpa.org/examples/som.html) to classify the data. From kohonen SOM with automatic class detection how to find out the only the number of classes inferred?